# Passing data from stateless widget to Stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this custom class with data, Which called it a stateless widget, and that stateless widget called in the stateful widget but Not sure how I can pass the data to stateful widget?

```
Model 
class ListOfIcon {
  String title;
  String imgurl;
  ListOfIcon({
    this.title,
    this.imgurl,
  });
}
```

Data :

```
final List<ListOfIcon> listoficons = [
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
];
```

Stateless Widget :

```
class RowOFIcons extends StatelessWidget {
  final ListOfIcon listOfIcon;

  const RowOFIcons({
    Key key,
    this.listOfIcon,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 6,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Text(
            listOfIcon.title,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

stateful widget :

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  double _scrolloffset = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          _scrolloffset = _scrollController.offset;
        });
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(screenSize.width, 50.0),
        child: CustomAppBar(
          scrollOffset: _scrolloffset,
        ),
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: [
          SliverPadding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            sliver: ProfilePhoto(),
          ),
          SliverPadding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            sliver: RowOFIcons(
              listOfIcon: listoficons.,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hi, I have this custom class with data, Which called it a stateless widget, and that stateless widget called in the stateful widget but Not sure how I can pass the data to stateful widget?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass data from child widget to parent widget?

Comment: Exactly, Parent is a stateful widget and child is  stateless widget ( Data called in stateless widget initially)

Answer (score 0):

Stateless Widget

```
class RowOFIcons extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ListOfIcon> listoficons = [
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
  ListOfIcon(title: 'fsdf', imgurl: 'assets/images/p4.jpg'),
];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 6,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Text(
            listoficons[index].title,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Stateful Widget

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(screenSize.width, 50.0),
        child: CustomAppBar(
          scrollOffset: _scrolloffset,
        ),
      ),
      body: RowOFIcons(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you Ujjwal. But this is not working and my problem is stateful widget not stateless

Comment: i have made some changes, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to StatefulWidget in a constructor like you pass data to a stateless widget. The only difference is the way you access it. For example:

```
class ExampleStateful extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget accepts a title
  final String title;
  ExampleStateful({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleStatefulState createState() => _ExampleStatefulState();
}

class _ExampleStatefulState extends State<ExampleStateful> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      // Accessing the title with widget.title
      child: Text(widget.title),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleStateless extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      // Passing the title as parameter
      child: ExampleStateful(
        title: 'Hello World :)',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Watch the comments I made in the code. Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thank you, Yair. But my problem is I called the stateless widget in stateful widget. I need to access the data from the stateless widget in the stateful widget.

Comment: Really appreciated it, man. But not working so I just hard code the data in stateless widget at least for now

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a state management solution. Learn about it [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro).